# asp.net mvc 3 - don't have option in project properties for "SSL Enabled"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, ssl, security

I'm following the Pluralsight ASP.NET MVC 3 [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc), module 7 - Security (which, by the way, is a great tutorial). In the Authorization section, at the 6:24 mark, it shows how to set the project property of `SSL Enabled` to `true`. My problem is, when I get into the project properties, I do not have that option.  I only see `Always Start When Debugging`, `Project File`, and `Project Folder`. Does anyone know why I don't have the option for `SSL Enabled`, how I could make it appear, or a different way I can achieve the same result? I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1Rel.

In other reading, I saw someting about the setting `requireSSL="true"` in the Web.config file, under the `authentication` tag. Does this do the same thing as setting `SSL Enabled = true` under project properties? If not, could anyone give a brief explanation of the difference or point me to a good article? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just figured out that this option is available if using IIS Express in the development environment, but not if using the VS Development Server, which my project was using. I solved my problem by right-clicking on the project in the Project Explorer window, then selecting "Configure Project for IIS" or something to that effect. Now the option for `SSL Enabled` shows up in the properties.

By the way, [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) is the web page that helped me figure out my problem.

Also, even though I figured out my primary question, I'd still be interested in any comments regarding my secondary question.

[EDIT] The shortcut to setting this is to right click on your project name in "Solution Explorer" and click Properties...In the Properties window, click on the "Web" tab, and then under "Servers" change the dropdown box to "IIS Express".

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using VS 2010 Express SP1Rel. I'm not sure what VS Ultimate is, so I'm assuming I'm not using it.

Comment: Mine was disabled, even though I was using IIS Express. But switching to normal IIS, then back to Express immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The RequireSSL property set in the configuration file for an ASP.NET application by using the requireSSL attribute of the forms configuration element.

Given that you are using asp.net mvc you can mark an action to be secure

like this:

```
[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult Login()
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The tutorial also discusses using the RequireHttps attribute, so I think there's a difference between this attr and setting SSL Enabled = true. I'll need to get further into the tutorial to see what each is actually doing. However, I think I found an answer to my question, which I'll post now.

Answer (score 1):

See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/better-faster-easier-ssl-testing-for-asp-net-mvc-amp-webforms.aspx
I recommend testing with IIS 7.5 (localserver)  - see [Test your ASP.NET MVC or WebForms Application on IIS 7 in 30 seconds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/04/22/test-you-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds.aspx)
The right way to require SSL is via

```
filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute());
```

See my blog post [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 4 App and the new AllowAnonymous Attribute](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm reading over the articles and at first glance they seem really useful. My app is MVC 3, so I'll need to implement custom class(es) to get the effect of AllowAnonymous MVC 4. I really like the idea of the global AuthorizeAttribute, then decorating with AllowAnonymous for specific actions.

Comment: AllowAnon trivial to implement in MVC 3. You probably saw my blog on that http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx